# Minipage-Enumerate combination problems

Tags: enumerate, minipage

I have been trying to split the page to save space to make it look more appealing.
This is the code I came up with:

```
\subsection*{Services:}
\begin{enumerate}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \item Bows
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Packaging for bows
        \item Bows for bottles
        \item Cosmetic bows
        \item Panettone-grind
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
   \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \item Ribbons
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Plain ribbons
        \item Motiv ribbons
        \item Individualized ribbons
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
```

and this is how it looked:

[image: Look]

For the most part it is what I wanted it but I wanted the numbers to be at the same level not have that weird offset.

I have also tried to make a line in between the minipages. this is how I thought I can do it:

```
\subsection*{Services:}
\begin{enumerate}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \item Bows
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Packaging for bows
        \item Bows for bottles
        \item Cosmetic bows
        \item Panettone-grind
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
  % \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\textwidth}}
    \item Ribbons
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Plain ribbons
        \item Motiv ribbons
        \item Individualized ribbons
    \end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
```

And this is how it turned out :
[image: Second]

btw I don't know what to do, I thought I can probably do it by manipulating margins for any of these components but I'm fairly new and don't know what to do.

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to replace both instances of `\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}` with `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}`, to **t**op-align the minipages. (By default, adjacent `minipage` environments are centered vertically.)

Comment: Well It pushed it down in a weird way

  [image](https://imgur.com/a/Mt3f6OF)

Comment: Did you apply the `[t]` positioning specifier to *both*  minipages or just to the first?

Comment: I used it on both of them. I had used it on another section of the same page with itemizing and It worked but with this specific section and this specific example I shared it was more offset when I used [t] ( Yes I did it for both mini pages)

Comment: Please see the brief answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `multicols` may be a good solution, I think: simple and it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Services:}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Bows
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Packaging for bows
        \item Bows for bottles
        \item Cosmetic bows
        \item Panettone-grind
    \end{itemize}
\columnbreak
    \item Ribbons
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Plain ribbons
        \item Motiv ribbons
        \item Individualized ribbons
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple to obtain this layout with the `tasks` package and its eponymous environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Services:}
\begin{tasks}[label=\arabic*. ](2)
    \task Bows
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Packaging for bows
        \item Bows for bottles
        \item Cosmetic bows
        \item Panettone-grind
    \end{itemize}
%
    \task Ribbons
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Plain ribbons
        \item Motiv ribbons
        \item Individualized ribbons
    \end{itemize}
\end{tasks}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the Task command what is splitting the page here ? and is the (2) what's allowing the page to split into 2 parts rather then 3 or more ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly with ”splitting the page”. Horizontally? For your second question, yes, it fixes the number of tasks per line.

Comment: oh my bad I meant Vertically. sorry

Comment: If it's vertically, I didn't have it. Could you post  a short, yet complete, code reproducing the problem?

Comment: There was no problem I just meant to ask whether the Task function is what causes the "minipages" to happen that way automatically.

Comment: ??? I didn't use any minipage with `tasks`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for confusing you. I meant that desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

If I (a) make your code snippet minimally compilable by prefixing it with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}` and affixing `\end{document}` to it and (b) replace *both* instances of `\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}` with `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}`, i.e., if I insert the `[t]` placement specifier in two places, I get the following result:

[image]

If you get something vastly different, do please tell us which document class you employ and which list-related packages (such as `enumitem` and `enumerate`) are loaded by your document.

Comment: Thank you it worked and it's clean. for future uses would it be okay if I split the same enumerate and have the same structure and \columnbreak and continue my itemization normally ?

Comment: I'm using multiple packages since my document is long ( by the look of it it will end up being 80 pages at least ) but I'm using `{enumitem}` My document class is `\documentclass[oneside,12pt, inner=2.5cm,Outer=2.5cm,Top=2.5cm,Bottom=2.5cm]{Classes/aesm_edspia}`